# pl/sql select subquery has invalid identifier - can't use new subquery in "where"

Tags: select, plsql, subquery

I dont understand why I can `order by` the new subquery, but at the same time can't query it with `where` as if I haven't defined the `COMMENT_COUNTED`

```
SELECT USERNAME,
  (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
   FROM COMMENTS coms
   WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
FROM USERS usrs 
WHERE COMMENT_COUNTED >= 3
ORDER by COMMENT_COUNTED desc;
```

I have also tried `WHERE COMMENT_COUNTED.COMMENT_COUNT >= 3`

My error message:

```
ORA-00904: "COMMENT_COUNTED"."COMMENT_COUNT": invalid identifier
```

EDIT: I've have a bad "solution". It does works, but I really want to find another way. I can just put the same subquery in `WHERE` and compare if it is >=3 like this:

```
SELECT USERNAME,
  (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
   FROM COMMENTS coms
   WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
FROM USERS usrs 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
   FROM COMMENTS coms
   WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) >= 3
ORDER by COMMENT_COUNTED desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMMENT_COUNTED` isn't created until after the where clause is executed. The execution flow of SQL is largely bottom up in terms of the structure of the query, but we write and interpret it top down.

The other answers have provided corrected queries, but never explained why your attempt isn't working.

Here's another approach:

```
select * from (
    SELECT USERNAME,
      (
       SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
       FROM COMMENTS coms
       WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY
      ) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
    FROM USERS usrs
) as a
WHERE a.COMMENT_COUNTED >= 3
ORDER by a.COMMENT_COUNTED desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

Either:

```
with tbl as(SELECT C_KEY AS COMMENT_COUNT
            FROM COMMENTS  )                       
 SELECT USERNAME,count(coms.COMMENT_COUNT)        
    FROM USERS usrs
    join tbl coms
    on coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY
   WHERE coms.COMMENT_COUNT >= 3
ORDER BY coms.COMMENT_COUNT DESC;
```

Or:

```
 SELECT USERNAME,count(coms.C_KEY)        
    FROM USERS usrs
    join COMMENTS coms
    on coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY
   WHERE coms.C_KEY >= 3
ORDER BY coms.C_KEY DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the order by the new sub-query, you can order by the number of the column like this:

```
SELECT USERNAME,
       (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
        FROM COMMENTS coms
        WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
FROM USERS usrs 
WHERE COMMENT_COUNTED >= 3
ORDER by 2 desc;
```

If you need to use the data into the where there are **three** options:

I. put the same sub-query in the where clause

```
SELECT USERNAME,
       (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
        FROM COMMENTS coms
        WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
FROM USERS usrs 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
       FROM COMMENTS coms
       WHERE coms.U_KEY = usrs.U_KEY) >= 3
ORDER by 2 desc;
```

II. Make a Query based on a sub-query:

```
SELECT USERNAME, COMMENT_COUNTED
FROM   (SELECT USERNAME,
               (SELECT COUNT(C_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNT
                FROM COMMENTS COMS
                WHERE COMS.U_KEY = USRS.U_KEY) AS COMMENT_COUNTED
        FROM USERS  
       ) USRS
WHERE COMMENT_COUNTED >= 3       
ORDER BY COMMENT_COUNTED DESC;
```

with this option you can use the column name into the ORDER BY clause.

**Update**:

III. Using the GROUP BY Clause and Aggregate Functions (*This is a better and clean solution*):

```
SELECT usrs.username AS username,
       COUNT(coms.c_key) AS comment_count
FROM   users usrs, comment_count coms
WHERE  coms.u_key = usrs.u_key
GROUP BY usrs.username
HAVING COUNT(coms.c_key) >= 3
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```